# Elemento excedendo o tamanho da div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma `col-md-4` que tem uma figure e uma `figcaption`, ao passar o mouse em cima deve ser exibida a `figcaption` com dois botõezinhos o efeito funciona, o problema é que a `figcaption` está excedendo a largura da imagem. Alguma sugestão?

Note que se eu passar o mouse na área em branco ao lado da imagem o efeito também ocorre, quando deveria ocorrer apenas ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/hidrau.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/Gescolar.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
        <figcaption>
        <a href="http://hidrauriomangueiras.com.br" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Visitar</button></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/hidraurio" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Github</button></a>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/hidrau.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
      </figure>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio figure{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#portfolio img{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

#portfolio figure figcaption{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#portfolio figure:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
#portfolio figure:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Comment: Está faltando o código HTML e o código no GitHub não está linkado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar `display: table` no CSS `#portfolio figure`, desta forma as dimensões do elemento `figure` se ajustarão às dimensões de `img` e não mais da tela.

```css
#portfolio figure{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}
#portfolio img{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

#portfolio figure figcaption{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#portfolio figure:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
#portfolio figure:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
        <figcaption>
          <a href="http://hidrauriomangueiras.com.br" target="_blank">
            <button class="btn-legenda">Visitar</button>
          </a>
          <a href="https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/hidraurio" target="_blank">
            <button class="btn-legenda">Github</button>
          </a>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
      </figure>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O efeto agora funcionou perfeitamente, mas os elementos deram uma andada pra esquerda kkk alguma sugestão para acertar? Pensei em aumentar o padding, ou a margin...